# Parse fasta file headers

Tags: python, perl, parsing, awk

I would like to add, for each fasta header, an additional column containing field four separated by space from the rest (supposing '|' is the field separator in input file headers).

No feasible idea this time.

Input file:

```
>gi|568301760|ref|NC_023137.1| Phaeobacter gallaeciensis DSM 26640, complete genome
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Desired output:

```
>NC_023137.1 gi|568301760|ref|NC_023137.1| Phaeobacter gallaeciensis DSM 26640, complete genome
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: Perhaps you should try and find a nice module that can parse fasta files for you?

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Bio::Perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some like this:

```
awk -F"[>|]" '/^>/ {$1=">"$5}8' OFS="|" file
>NC_023137.1|gi|568301760|ref|NC_023137.1| Phaeobacter gallaeciensis DSM 26640, complete genome
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

This should get the `>` and `|` correct:

```
awk -F"[|]" '/^>/ {$0=substr($0,1,1)$4" "substr($0,2)}1' file
>NC_023137.1 gi|568301760|ref|NC_023137.1| Phaeobacter gallaeciensis DSM 26640, complete genome
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Answer (score 1):

A Perl option:

```
perl -F"[>|]" -pae 's/^>/>$F[4] /' file.fa
```

Output:

```
>NC_023137.1 gi|568301760|ref|NC_023137.1| Phaeobacter gallaeciensis DSM 26640, complete genome
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

Hope this helps!